# Proof of authority reward mechanism

Tags: consensus, proof-of-authority, poa, reward

1. Can anybody explain the reward mechanism in Proof of Authority (PoA)
   protocol? What kind of reward is received by the validators in PoA?

   So far I came up with the following points:

   - There is no competition between miners, new blocks are created by the authorized nodes at any time.
   - As there is no mining in PoA so there is no reward mechanism.
   - The winning block contains only a header and address of the miner for reward.

   But, I could not figure out what is the reward actually. Is this
   ether, transaction fee in gas or something else?
2. One incentive I could figure out is that individuals maintain their
       identity as a validator. Is there any other incentive for the
       validators?

Answer (score 0):

The sealer does receive the transaction fee